# Building TBB using Visual Studio 2015 x64 and CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, tbb

i would like to build TBB to use it in another CMake project. I tried to build TBB from the [Github source](https://github.com/01org/tbb) using the [makefile](https://github.com/01org/tbb/tree/tbb_2019/build/vs2013) (upgraded with VisualStudio 2015). This failed due to a mysterious error:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'opencv_core300.lib'`

Where does this error could originate from?

My second try was is to build TBB using another [repository](https://github.com/wjakob/tbb) that allows a build using CMake. This build produces an tbb.lib, tbb.dll, etc. file.
Now I am stuck how to incorporate is in my other cmake files. There is no TBBConfig.cmake or similar. 
My CMakeLists.txt for my project looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(IntrafraktionelleRegistrierung)

find_package(ITK REQUIRED
 COMPONENTS 
    ITKRegistrationCommon
    ITKRegistrationMethodsv4
)

include(${ITK_USE_FILE})
set(SRC
    ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.cxx
)

if (DEFINED ENV{TBBROOT})
    message(STATUS "TBBROOT: $ENV{TBBROOT}")    
else()
    message(STATUS "TBBROOT not defined!")
endif()

find_package(TBB REQUIRED)  
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC})
target_link_libraries( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    ${ITK_LIBRARIES}
    tbb
)'
```

TBBROOT is the build directory of tbb. The FindTBB.cmake I have available is borrowed from [here](https://github.com/justusc/FindTBB/blob/master/FindTBB.cmake) and copied to the modules directory of cmake.

The latest version of the [binaries of TBB](https://github.com/01org/tbb/releases) have a CMake folder with TBBConfig.cmake inside. I used this to link the TBB to my project but somehow I ended up by an error stating: "tbb-NOTFOUND.obj cannot be found". (This way is still under investigation.

Has someone used this repository to configure and build a cmake project?

Comment: if it builds using `CMake` it should generate the `TBBConfig.cmake` in the build tree.

Comment: ***Where does this error could originate from?*** You don't have the opencv libraries in the path that the makefile expects or maybe you are mixing 32 and 64 bits.

Comment: Did you set the  `TBBROOT` environment variable to point to the build folder of the TBB project? Note that with `CMake` when configuring you usually use a different folder for building versus the source.

Comment: `if (DEFINED ENV{TBBROOT})` you are missing a $ before the ENV it should be: `if (DEFINED $ENV{TBBROOT})`

Comment: I checked it twice: no TBBConfig.cmake file was created.

Comment: `ìf (DEFINED ENV{TBBROOT})` checks if the variable is defined (see [CMake:IF](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html)). The $ resolves the variable for the value as you can see on the next line. This snippet is just a check if an enviromental variable with the name of TBBROOT is defined

Comment: The TBBROOT points towards the build directory. I prefer out-of-source builds.

Comment: ***This snippet is just a check if an enviromental variable with the name of TBBROOT is defined*** I know that I was explaining that your code had a bug / typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About CMake related questions

Basically you have two options:

- Integration of pre-built TBB binaries into your project

  You can use the [binaries of TBB](https://github.com/01org/tbb/releases) (just as you did) according to the following [example](https://github.com/01org/tbb/tree/tbb_2019/cmake#binary-intel-tbb-integration-to-the-sub-string-finder-sample-windows-os). After invocation of `find_package(TBB REQUIRED)` you will get TBB targets in a format `TBB::<component>` (e.g. `TBB::tbb`, `TBB::tbbmalloc`, etc). Also `TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS` variable will contain all imported TBB targets.

  So, you need to slightly modify your `target_link_libraries`:

  ```
  target_link_libraries( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
      ${ITK_LIBRARIES}
      ${TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS}
  )
  ```

  or

  ```
  target_link_libraries( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
      ${ITK_LIBRARIES}
      TBB::tbb
  )
  ```

  Also you can update your `find_package` if you need only `TBB::tbb` component in your project: `find_package(TBB REQUIRED tbb)`
- Integration of TBB source code into your project

  You can use `tbb_build` (it is a CMake wrapper using GNU Make on TBB Makefiles), but to run it on Windows under Visual Studio you will need to have GNU Make in your environment.

  If you'd like to integrate this [TBB (with CMake support)](https://github.com/wjakob/tbb) you can use `add_subdirectory(<YOUR-TBB-ROOT>)` (replace `<YOUR-TBB-ROOT>` with actual location of TBB) instead of `find_package(TBB REQUIRED)`.